# ¿Como puedo ocultar un f:selectItem de un p:selectOneRadio en JSF?

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

Aqui les muestro la porción de codigo del componente p:selectOneRadio

```
<p:selectOneRadio id="console" value="#{archivamientoView.archivamientoDTO.tipoProcesoArchiva}">
                                 <f:selectItem itemLabel="Denuncia"   itemValue="DENU" itemDisabled="#{archivamientoView.itemDenunciaDisabled}" />
                                 <f:selectItem itemLabel="Expediente" itemValue="EXPE" itemDisabled="#{archivamientoView.itemExpedienteDisabled}"/>                          
                            </p:selectOneRadio>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar la etiqueta `c:if`.

Lo primero es declarar el uso de las etiquetas `c` con:

```
<html xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
```

Después:

```
<p:selectOneRadio id="console" value="#{archivamientoView.archivamientoDTO.tipoProcesoArchiva}">
    <c:if test="#{archivamientoView.visible}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Denuncia"   itemValue="DENU" itemDisabled="#{archivamientoView.itemDenunciaDisabled}" />
    </c:if>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Expediente" itemValue="EXPE" itemDisabled="#{archivamientoView.itemExpedienteDisabled}"/>                          
</p:selectOneRadio>
```

Por último declarar la propiedad `boolean visible` en tu clase Java.

Referencia: [SO EN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8179355/how-do-i-hide-the-fselectitem-tag-under-hselectoneradio#)